# Symfony2 persist again after prePersist or preUpdate is fired

Tags: php, symfony

I have one date field in my form.

I have used preUpdate and prePersist methods to set it to currentDate whenever my entity is added or updated .Previously this field was not in form and was being added/updated automatically.

Now i want to add this field into form so that user can set it to another date.But whenever i update it, it is always being set to current date no matter what is being posted by the form.

Please help.This is my code.

```
   $allocation->setVehicle($vehicle);
   $allocation->setType($type);
   $em->persist($allocation);
   $em->flush();

   $allocation->setMutationDate($date->getMutationDate());

   $em->persist()
   $em->flush();
```

Comment: Well, if you still use prePersist and preUpdate, then of course it will override the user's choice.

Comment: @EmanuelOster, actually this date is also being set to current date when a user changes anything else. So i wanted to use lifecycle callbacks but not in this specific case, any way i can override prePersist value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a private flag to your entity, something like `mutationDateModified`.
Set this to true within the setter of mutationDate. Then, in prePersist/preUpdate, check if mutationDateModified is true. If yes, don't update mutationDate. Either way, set mutationDateModified back to false afterwards.

Comment: Woaah!
Logical delight
Thanks a lot